# Android: Images not downloading from server

Tags: php, android, image, server

I have uploaded few images on my server which will be downloaded to my android application by passing a `url`. I have written a `php` file which displays the image. I pass the `URL` to my android application like this :

'http://myURL/getImage.php?image=logo.png'.

When I copy paste the `URL` directly in browser the image is displayed correctly.
However the image file is not getting downloaded on my android application. I know that android code is correct because when I am giving any other random image `URL` the image is downloading correctly. Do I have to give something else in my php file to make the image 'downloadable'.

**Image.php**

```
<?php

  echo '<img src="Images/'.$_REQUEST['image'].'"/><br />';

 ?>
```

Comment: where is you android(java) code?

Comment: simply ... it is not an image .... it is HTML page with img tag ... you need send a binary image not HTML page ... and no I don't know how to do this cuase i don't like PHP but it should be easy to find by using google (30sec.) ... **edit:** you can also change the link to `http://myURL/Images/logo.png` and this link should return the image binary itself (it should be obvious)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting HTML but I have to use php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want the PHP to **output the image directly**. Instead, your code is generating **an HTML with the image on it**. Although your browser displays similar results, the underlying content is different.

What you actually need could be this:

```php
<?php

$filepath = 'Images/'.$_REQUEST['image'];
$filename = basename($filepath);
$ctype = 'image/jpeg'; // assuming it is a .jpg file

if (is_file($filepath)) {
    header('Content-Type: '.$ctype);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    echo file_get_contents($file);
    exit();
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    // you may add some other message here
    exit();
}
```

This is vulnerable to hazardous `$_REQUEST['image']` input. Just filter it somehow. Also you must generate the correct `$ctype` for the image file.